# sumif considers '3.1 and '3.10 equal in criteria

Tags: excel, criteria, sumifs

In Excel sheet we have

```
    A      B

2  '3.1    8500
3  '3.10   140

6  '3.1    =SUMIF($A$2:$A$4,OFFSET(B$6,0,-1,1,1),B$2:B$4)
7  '3.10   =SUMIF($A$2:$A$4,OFFSET(B$7,0,-1,1,1),B$2:B$4)
```

The result for sumif functions follows

```
6  '3.1    8640
7  '3.10  8640
```

It seems that excel ignores '3.10 and considers it as '3.1
What is wrong?
How we can make Excel to consider '3.10 not as '3.1 ?

Office 2016
Windows 10

Comment: `SUMIF` will convert text to a number if it can, so both `'3.1` and `'3.10` get converted to the number `3.1` which is why they have the same sumif result.  If you need them differentiated, use `SUMPRODUCT` instead: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4=A6)*$B$2:$B$4)`

Comment: Why the unnecessary use of OFFSET? `OFFSET(B$7,0,-1,1,1)` is the same as `A$7`